# Python compare value and leave loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Good afternoon.
How do I access the result of take_name_res_list at the end of the string if I only get the last result.

Comment: If you need a code, I can send it, only when creating a request, the system did not let it through

Comment: Please read the community guide on [how to ask a question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The question as is, is not answerable due to lack of context/information.

Comment: You need to include a [mcve] and explain what your description has in connection with your title

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74769903/edit) your question to include the relevant code.